# Detect when angular application access external URL ( not in router )

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I need to detect the event when angular application access/navigate to external url like youtube.com or google.com .
Since these are not in the application router paths, we can't use router.events .
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Does one of your button sends to such an url, or do you want to see if the user types a new url in its navbar ?

Comment: button sends to such url, or even <a> tag can.

Comment: then you can have a look to [this site](https://adrianfaciu.dev/posts/angular-router-external-links/) (you may skip the directive part). You you make an internal route, which redirects to any external link. So external links will first go through your internal link, and you can do whatever you want there